# Elasticsearch terms aggregation and querying

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, group-by, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have two types of log messages:

```
Jul 23 09:24:16 rrr mrr-core[222]: Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656871111.mt processMTMessage() #12798 realtime: 5.684 ms

Jul 23 09:24:18 rrr mrr-core[2222]: Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656871111.0.dn processDN() #7750 realtime: 1.382 ms
```

The first message is kind of sent message and second is message which confirm that message was delivered.

The difference between them is the suffix which I have separated from "id" and can query it.

These messages are parsed and stored in elasticsearch in following format:

```
messageId: Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656871111.0.dn
text: Aweg3AOMTs
num1: 1563866656871111
num2: 0
suffix: mt/dn
```

I would like to find out which messages were succesfully delivered and which weren't. I am very beginner in elasticsearch so I'm really struggling.

I'm trying terms aggregations at the moment but all I could've achieved is this code:

```
GET /my_index3/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "num1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "messageId.keyword",
        "include": ".*mt*."
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Which shows me the sent messages. I don't know how to add some filter there or clause that could show me only messages having both mt and dn suffix.

If anyone has an idea I'd be really thankful :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the terms aggregation on messageId.keyword is not that good, as each message is different ('Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656871111.0.dn' is not the same as 'Aweg3AOMTs_1563866656871111.mt').

From looking at the docs structure, I think you better run the terms aggregation on `num1` which is the common part of the .mt and .dn messages. That aggregation will give you the count of messages for each unique num1. So for each message which got a request & response the count would be 2, a message with only request would have a count of 1.

If you also want to see the number itself, you can add a nested aggregation inside, like top-hits aggregation with size 1, that would display the `num1` field inside:

```
GET /my_index3/_search {
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "num1": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "num1",
            "order": {
                "_count": "desc"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "count_of_distinct_suffix": {
                    "cardinality": {
                        "field": "suffix"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "filter_count_is_2": {
                            "bucket_selector": {
                                "buckets_path": {
                                    "the_doc_count": "_count"
                                },
                                "script": "the_doc_count == 2"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply!!
So how can I get only messages that matches so they have both mt and dn suffix? How can I manage the count 2 you talking about...
The code you sent shows all num1 values.

Comment: You need to add sort (decending).

Comment: I updated the terms agg above to include sorting. now, the first items your'll get on the list will be with count=2, and only after those you'll see the ones with count=1. you can also reverse the sorting order if you want to get those with count=1 before. So, as long as the amount of log pairs is not too big, you can get them all and filter the ones you want

Comment: Thanks for help! But I still don't know how can I filter the num1's that have botch ('dn' and 'mt' suffix) :

Comment: If I understand you better, there are few messages with the same 'num1', some have 'dn' suffix and some 'mt'. So, you can add an inner nested aggregation - cardinality that count how many distinct suffix exists - should be either 1 or 2. I've updated the query above

Comment: This just gets me all num1's I have stored. I need to find only num1's that have dn and mt suffix simultaneously!! That's the goal :D

Comment: Sorry, I probably still don't understand you fully :) the way my query is build it first aggregate based on the num1 values, so the upper level buckets each count docs with the same num1 value. then, in each bucket it then count how many different unique suffix exists, so it the inner agg count is 2 it means that for the same value of num1 there are 2 different suffix, which is like what you wrote "have dn and mt suffix simultaneously" so the way I understood it does exactly that.

Comment: Oh now I see. Sorry that's my very first elasticsearch experience so I still don't know a lot of things. Now I know what you meant, but is there any option to see ONLY results where count_of_distinct_suffix is 2? I tried add min_doc_count = 2 at the end of query but it didn't work :(

Comment: you can use bucket selector for that: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html  (see example here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filter-based-on-the-doc-count-with-aggregations/62677)

Comment: I've updated the original answer to add the filtering for count == 2, as example

Comment: Ziv, thank you very much you are a savior. Unfortunately when I try to run the code there is an error: "Aggregator [count_of_distinct_suffix] of type [cardinality] cannot accept sub-aggregations"

Comment: So you need to put the bucket selector as a sub-aggregation of the terms aggregation. See example of terms+selector here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html

Comment: Now it works just fine! There was problem with brackets. Is there any possibility to do time range for recieving the second suffix. I mean that num1 has only 1 suffix and if the same num1 didn't get second suffix within some time e.g one hour it wouldn't show this bucket even if the_doc_count == 2

Comment: You are welcome. Few options to continue - either add a higher level date histogram aggregation as a top level, this way you can break the interval to hourly/time-based buckets. you can also use composite aggregation in order to scan through all the results. anyway, it is a bit more complicated then that, as splitting to buckets may cause having one suffix in one bucket and the second one in the following bucket, and they would look like there's no pair, because the pair is split between buckets. I suggest that if you have more questions open a new thread, as this is too long. good luck